# Flutter floating action button customise

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to create a Flutter application where a floating action button can be clicked to make a container slide up. I have attached an image of how it works. Please help me achieve this.

```dart
AnimatedOpacity(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  opacity: ref.watch(floatingButtionShow) ? 0.5 : 0.0,
  child: AnimatedPositioned(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    bottom: ref.watch(floatingButtionShow) ? 100 : -10,
    child: Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 150,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Floating Container',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I am trying to make this container appear in the center of the screen when the floating action button is clicked.

This is what I need:

[image: This is what I need]

Comment: Container(
      height: 155,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(
            Assets.images.floating.path,
          ),
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),
      ), I created container. then set SVG design to background

Answer (score 0):

you can use this and do whatever you want.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 150,
                child: Text(
                  'Floating Container',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
              ClipPath(
                clipper: MyClipper(),
                child: Container(
                  height: 20,
                  width: 400,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),


 class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
 @override
 Path getClip(Size size) {
 var firstOffset = Offset(size.width * 0.45, 0.0);
 var secondPoint = Offset(size.width * 0.50, size.height);
 var lastPoint = Offset(size.width * 0.55, 0.0);
 var path = Path()
   ..moveTo(firstOffset.dx, firstOffset.dy)
   ..lineTo(secondPoint.dx, secondPoint.dy)
   ..lineTo(lastPoint.dx, lastPoint.dy)
   ..close();

 return path;
 }

 @override
 bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
   return true;
 }
}
```

[this is the result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmRnn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).